# Find the first $3$ terms of the two possible geometric progressions.

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

The fourth term of a G.P is $3$ and the sixth term is $147$. Find the first $3$ terms of the two possible geometric progressions.

Can you help me find $a$ and $r$? It is too complicated. I took two simultaneous equations

$$ar^3=3 ------- (1)$$

$$ar^5=147------- (2)$$

$$r= \sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{a}}------(3)$$

I did this, and then it gets complicated because of that cubic root...

i got $a=0.672$ and $r=1.67$ which is wrong. Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide $ar^5$ by $ar^3$. You should get $r^2=\frac{147}{3}$. Thus $r=\pm 7$. Now for each value of $r$ the appropriate $a$ is not hard to find.

Comment: that means a is right?

Comment: should i divide (2) / (1)?

Comment: There are two cases. If $r=7$, then $a=\frac{3}{r^3}=\frac{3}{343}$. The other case gives you $a=-\frac{3}{343}$. But first we needed $r$, which is obtained by finding $\frac{ar^5}{ar^3}$. Alternately we could find $a$ first, but that is somewhat more messy.

Comment: alright...lemme try :) thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. The answer I gave should be enough for you to finish the rest of the calculation.

Comment: yeah i guess um getting it right now :)